# Multiple Results Per Model from Test Set

Tags: r

I'm trying to create multiple observations per model from my test set so that I have enough model results to run statistical tests of significance for differences across the models. The models I'm comparing are different types, such as random forest, logistic regression, etc.

To do so, I was going to create folds in my test set and run the model against each fold to generate multiple observations per model.

**Does this approach make sense, or is there another way to do it?** I know cross-validation generates multiple results per model, but I'm not training the model, just predicting results from the final already-established model.

The code is something like the following, where dfList is the list of folds created from my test set:

```
 for(i in 1:length(dfList)) {
      
      testdata <- as.data.frame(dfList[[i]])
      result[[i]] <- predict(forwards, testdata, type = "response") 

     # model       <- glm(isFraud~.,family=binomial (link = "logit"),data=trainData)
      
      toselect.x <- summary(forwards)$coeff[-1,4] < 0.05
      
      # select sig. variables
      relevant.x <- names(toselect.x)[toselect.x == TRUE] 
      
     # install.packages("vctrs")
     #  library(vctrs)
      
      #count vars
      numvar <- vec_count(relevant.x)
      
      summary[[i]] <- auc(testdata$isFraud, result[[i]])
    }
```